# Components of acceleration in spherical polar co-ordinate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems

I wanted to calculate two component of acceleration in polar co-ordinate. Starting from the lagrangian

$$L= \frac{1}{2}m(   \dot{r} ^{2}+ r^{2}    \dot{ \theta } ^{2}   ) -V(r, \theta )$$

I calculated two lagrange equation for $r$ and $\theta$

$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial  \dot{ \theta }  } - \frac{\partial L}{\partial  \theta  } = 0 $$

$$\Rightarrow m( r \ddot{ \theta }+2 \dot{r} \dot{ \theta }    )=-   \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial V}{\partial  \theta } $$

and

$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial  \dot{ r }  } - \frac{\partial L}{\partial  r  } = 0 $$

$$\Rightarrow m( \ddot{ r }- r  \dot{ \theta }^{2}     )=-    \frac{\partial V}{\partial  r } $$

which gives me components of acceleration in polar co-ordinate

$$ a_{r} =  \ddot{ r }- r  \dot{ \theta }^{2}    $$ and

$$a_{\theta} =r \ddot{ \theta }+2 \dot{r} \dot{ \theta }$$

I want to find the components of acceleration for spherical polar co-ordinate. I started from the lagrangian

$$L= \frac{1}{2}m(   \dot{r} ^{2}+ r^{2}    \dot{ \theta } ^{2}+   r^{2}  \sin ^2 \theta    \dot{  \phi  } ^{2}   ) -V(r, \theta, \phi  )$$

and calculated three lagrange equations, for $r$

$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial  \dot{ r }  } - \frac{\partial L}{\partial  r  } = 0 $$

$$ \Rightarrow m( \ddot{r}-r  \dot{ \theta } ^{2}-r \sin ^2 \theta   \dot{ \phi } ^{2}   )=-  \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} $$

for $\theta$

$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial  \dot{ \theta }  } - \frac{\partial L}{\partial  \theta  } = 0 $$

$$\Rightarrow m[ \frac{d}{dt}( r^{2} \sin ^2 \theta   \dot{ \phi } ^{2}  )- \frac{1}{2} r^{2} \sin 2 \theta   \dot{ \phi } ^{2}    ]=- \frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta} $$

for $\phi$

$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial  \dot{ \phi }  } - \frac{\partial L}{\partial  \phi  } = 0 $$

$$ \Rightarrow m \frac{d}{dt}( r^{2} \sin ^2 \theta  \dot{ \phi }  ) =- \frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi } $$

Now my question is what is the three components of acceleration in spherical polar co-ordinate?

Comment: The second equation should be $m\left(\frac{d}{dt} r\dot{\theta}-r^2 \sin(\theta) \dot{\phi}^2\right)=-\frac{dV}{d\theta}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the vector components of acceleration, it may be insightful to write the laws in vector form:
$$m\mathbf{a} = -\nabla{V}$$

In spherical polar coordinates, we have the following components of the gradient:
$$(\nabla V)_r  = \frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$$
$$(\nabla V)_\theta = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta}$$
$$(\nabla V)_\phi = \frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi}$$

This should directly take you to the components $a_r$, $a_\theta$, $a_\phi$ from the Euler-Lagrange equations in $r$, $\theta$, $\phi$ respectively, just like what you have already done for the plane polar coordinates in two dimensions.